# iPad swipe Gesture Mobile Safari

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

I have been googling around for a bit and am trying to determine how to do a simple swipe event across an html element such as a div, to cause some action to happen in javascript.

```
<div id="swipe_me">
Swipe Test
</div>
```

Can someone show me or point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

javascript.

something a bit like (untested code)

```
                onInitialized: function(e, slider) {

    var time = 1000, // allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
        range = 100,  // swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the slider
        x = 0, t = 0, touch = "ontouchend" in document,
        st = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
        mv = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
        en = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

    slider.$window
        .bind(st, function(e){
            // prevent image drag (Firefox)
            e.preventDefault();
            t = (new Date()).getTime();
            x = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
        })
        .bind(en, function(e){
            t = 0; x = 0;
        })
        .bind(mv, function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var newx = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
            r = (x === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(newx - x),
            // allow if movement < 1 sec
            ct = (new Date()).getTime();
            if (t !== 0 && ct - t < time && r > range) {
                if (newx < x) { slider.goForward(); }
                if (newx > x) { slider.goBack(); }
                t = 0; x = 0;
            }
        });
}
```